# If I plan to drive on soft ground, what can I do to avoid sinking in?

Tags: transport, soil

I'm expecting tons of wood chips to be dropped off in part of my yard every day this year, and am wondering what I need to do so the arborist can easily drop them off as close to where I want them as possible while staying happy (not sinking into swampy soil, or tractor eating ground)?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to Sustainable Living.

Comment: it is related to driving on a type of minimum maintenance road

Comment: Woodchips are very valuable to homesteaders (and folks with large gardens/yards), and homesteading is definitely all about sustainability.  Most environmentally conscious people also subscribe to "treading lightly upon the earth" — which is _literally_ what this question is about.  I think the question is fine.  I don't think it's wise or valuable to narrow the focus of SLSE to "solutions for city slickers".

Comment: @acoder Can you expand your question to include a little bit of information about existing access?  How many (viable) ways are there for the truck to access your property?  What fraction of the access is gravel/compacted sand/grass-over-clay?  How far into your property will they need to drive?

Comment: Also, do you actually mean *tons* of woodchips *every day* for a *whole* year?  That would be an absolutely insane amount of material to cope with.  A vertitable mountain of chips larger than most houses.

Comment: arborist truckloads of wood chips dumped into the garden for next year basically every day as the arborist is a neighbor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *usual* solution to avoid sinking into soft ground is to release some air from your tyres so that they bulge more.  That increases the contact area with the earth, distributes the weight of the vehicle over a larger area, and reduces the likelihood and depth of sinking.

It is highly unlikely, however, that a commercial service will do this for you.  They want a place where they can quickly pop in, drop off, and leave.  Ideally, the driver wouldn't even have to exit the cab of the vehicle.

If that's the case then you have no option but to control/modify the route that the trucks will take once they come through your gate.

If you have an existing, all-weather driveway, then use that.  If you don't have an all-weather driveway, or the condition of your driveway is 'marginal', then you want to divert the trucks off it as quickly as possible.

Dad was a logger.  Brush piles, and huge volumes of sawdust and wood chips were a by-product of the logging/milling operations he was involved in.  The local soil is sandy, but low spots exist that turn swampy/boggy in the wet season.  Their solution for temporary roads through boggy areas was a 50cm deep elevated roadway made of woody debris.

Paths turn to muddy bogs due to the hydraulic pumping action that occurs as tyres drive over a particular spot.  If you create a deep enough pile of chips, it will be free-draining, and hydraulic pumping won't occur at soil level.

So, my suggestion would be for you to divert incoming trucks from your driveway as quickly as possible and get them to dump their first load straight away.  You should sculpt the pile into a type of gentle off-ramp.  Subsequent loads should extend the ramp and increase its height. Repeat until the height of the ramp is "decent" (around here ~50cm supports logging trucks).  From that point on just extend the length of the elevated woodchip road as needed and route it wherever you want.

About the only maintenance required is to occasionally rake-in the chips from the sides to the compacted ('rut') areas, and to occasionally top up (level) sections that compact more than others.

I've only just noticed your previous question about pigs and woodchips.  Assuming that this is related to that, if/when the woodchip road is no longer required you can fence it off with an electric fence and let the pigs in to eat/dismantle the road.  What little the pigs miss will quickly break down and the grass will return.

Comment: how thick would wood chips need to be as I've seen a logging TV show,and noticed that they use trees, but I need to do it with wood chips for composting reasons I have an unlimited supply of the good 3 ply cardboard, and can lay wood chips on top of it if necessary.

Comment: the pigs is a different question than this one

Comment: I'm permanently killing grass, so i can easily "maneuver" around my garden.

Comment: The thickness that will work for you depends on your soil texture, rain/moisture levels, the dump truck mass and number of axles, and so-on.  No magic number exists that works for all situations.  "It depends."  You could start relatively thin (say 10cm) and see how it goes.  If you see it getting mushy, add another 10cm layer.  Repeat until it's stable.  Or just err on the side of caution and go deep right from the get-go.  Here 50cm of woody debris on sand works for 20+ ton log trucks.  YMMV.

Comment: so if i know the soil will eat tractors on the run start 6-12 inches on 3 ply cardboard?

Comment: Can't say what effect the cardboard will have — never seen/tried that.  It might disintegrate the moment it gets wet, and provide no support at all.  I don't think it would make things worse, however, so if you have a free supply you may as well try it (on at least one section of the road).  If the soil currently "eats tractors" then I wouldn't even consider 15cm — start at 30cm and add more if needed.  Oh, and if your land slopes across the road, lay down a PVC pipe under the cardboard/chips to act as a culvert so you don't accidentally end up with a dam on the uphill side.

Comment: it's not a "road", it's a "parking lot" (garden), so it's level.

Comment: 50cm?! In some wet forestry I've worked on, slash (woody debris, limbs from trees turned into logs) is dragged onto trails in piles 1-2m high, then driven on with heavy equipment and flattened to ~0.5-1m high. Pretty sketchy to walk on but works great to protect soil and water quality. As Tim said though YMMV in terms of depth needed. Overall this sounds like the right answer: drop a pathway of chips to support the truck as it backs in, and use cardboard to facilitate.

Comment: I've used cardboard to keep vehicles out of the mud but it doesn't work so well. It's more like a snowshoe distributing weight, not really the fluffy mat that woody debris serves as. I agree though that cardboard wouldn't hurt, you'll basically just be sheet mulching the garden dirt road.

Comment: My point about depth is that the material will get very compressed, so starting with 50cm is probably too little. Start with more and watch it shrink.